# Navigation out of a Compose activity in XML/Compose hybrid

Tags: android, xml, navigation, android-jetpack-compose, android-navigation

I am working on a personal project and experimenting with Jetpack Compose. I currently have the whole project in XML.
I just made a button that navigates to a new Fragment and Activity, but I used Compose to make that new activity a Composable. My question is: How do I navigate out (back) of that Compose activity safely and properly? My current solution is to get the activity with:

```
val activity = LocalContext.current as Activity
```

and to call:

```
onClick = {
    activity.finish()
}
```

Let me know how this fares and/or what is the ideal solution to deal with back navigation in an XML/Compose hybrid. This is the only Compose activity so using the Jetpack Navigator isn't the way I want to go.

Thanks in advance and great weekend!

Comment: Are you interested in using Fragment/Activity as container of your composables/composable screen?

Comment: Yes, this is what I am doing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed the correct way to end an activity from a composable.

Xml or composable doesnt matter since an activity is still an activity, it will finish his lifecycle and lifecycle of composables hosted by the activity will cleanly end too.

Only difference is how to get the activity instance, I would better suggest creating an extension function to get the activity more safely :

```
fun Context.getActivity(): AppCompatActivity? = when (this) {
is AppCompatActivity -> this
is ContextWrapper -> baseContext.getActivity()
else -> null
}
```

It will avoid potential crashes on your `LocalContext.current as Activity` since a context is not always an `activity` and can also be a `ContextWrapper`

and to end your activity on back press you could use Composable function `BackHandler` in your composable :

```
BackHandler {
    activity?.finish()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So this would be appropriate if my Composable is used in Activity/Fragment?

Comment: Yes this would be appropriate.
It works the same if your composable is used in a fragment, it will get the activity that host the fragment and finish it.